# Bad Performance of Shader on Phones, Works Good in Editor on Windows - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I just came across a strange issue with a shader (for rendering grass) on different dimensions of the object like 150 sq meters or 100 sq meters. It works fine and smoothly in editor but slows down the gameplay on android devices. I am using only one pass and completely noob with shaders.

Would appreciate anyone's help/clue on what's going on, as I expected it to be a quite light weight shader.

Thanks for coming here :)

```
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100
 
        Pass
        {
            Name "GeometryGrass"
 
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
 
            CGPROGRAM          
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
 
            sampler2D _GrassTex;
            float4 _GrassTex_ST;
 
            sampler2D _NoGrassTex;
            float4 _NoGrassTex_ST;
         
            #include "CustomTessellation.cginc"
 
            #pragma target 4.0
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma geometry geom
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_instancing
            #pragma hull hull
            #pragma domain domain
         
            float4 _TopColor;
            float4 _BottomColor;
            float _BendRotationRandom;
            float _RotationMultiplier;
 
            float _BladeHeight;
            float _BladeHeightRandom;  
            float _BladeWidth;
            float _BladeWidthRandom;
         
 
            vertexOutput makevertex(float3 pos, float2 cuv, float2 uv){
                vertexOutput o;
 
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
                o.uv = uv;
                o.cuv = cuv;
                o.normal = 0;
                o.tangent = 0;
 
                return o;
            }
         
            float rand(float3 myVector)  {
                return frac(sin(dot(myVector.xyz, float3(12.9898, 78.233, 53.539))) * 43758.5453);
            }
 
            float3x3 AngleAxis3x3(float angle, float3 axis)
            {
                float c, s;
                sincos(angle, s, c);
 
                float t = 1 - c;
                float x = axis.x;
                float y = axis.y;
                float z = axis.z;
 
                return float3x3(
                t * x * x + c, t * x * y - s * z, t * x * z + s * y,
                t * x * y + s * z, t * y * y + c, t * y * z - s * x,
                t * x * z - s * y, t * y * z + s * x, t * z * z + c
                );
            }
 
            [maxvertexcount(3)]
            void geom(triangle vertexInput IN[3], inout TriangleStream<vertexOutput> triStream)
            {
                float3 pos = IN[0].vertex;
                float3 vNormal = IN[0].normal;
                float4 vTangent = IN[0].tangent;
                float3 vBinormal = cross(vNormal, vTangent) * vTangent.w;
                float3 alpha = 1 - tex2Dlod(_NoGrassTex, float4(IN[0].uv, 0, 0));
             
 
                if(alpha.x > 0.5){
                    float3x3 tangentToLocal = float3x3(
                    vTangent.x, vBinormal.x, vNormal.x,
                    vTangent.y, vBinormal.y, vNormal.y,
                    vTangent.z, vBinormal.z, vNormal.z
                    );
 
                    float3x3 bendRotationMatrix = AngleAxis3x3(0, float3(0, 0, 0));//AngleAxis3x3(rand(pos.zzx) * _BendRotationRandom * sin(_Time[0] * _RotationMultiplier) * UNITY_PI * 0.5,float3(-1, 0, 0));
                    float3x3 facingRotationMatrix = AngleAxis3x3(rand(pos) * UNITY_TWO_PI, float3(0, 0, 1));
 
                    float3x3 transformationMatrix = tangentToLocal;
                    transformationMatrix = mul(transformationMatrix, facingRotationMatrix);
                    transformationMatrix = mul(transformationMatrix, bendRotationMatrix);
 
                    float height = (rand(pos.zyx) * 2 - 1) * _BladeHeightRandom + _BladeHeight;
                    float width = (rand(pos.xzy) * 2 - 1) * _BladeWidthRandom + _BladeWidth;
                 
                    triStream.Append(makevertex(pos + mul(transformationMatrix, float3(width, 0, 0)),float2(1, 0),IN[0].uv));
                    triStream.Append(makevertex(pos + mul(transformationMatrix, float3(-width, 0, 0)), float2(0, 0), IN[0].uv));
                    triStream.Append(makevertex(pos + mul(transformationMatrix, float3(0, 0, height)), float2(0.5, 1), IN[0].uv));
                    triStream.RestartStrip();
                }
            }
         
            fixed4 frag (vertexOutput i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_GrassTex, i.uv);
                col *= lerp(_BottomColor, _TopColor, i.cuv.y);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
```

I have removed all of the un necessary calculations but behavior does not seems to change.

Comment: Tesselation is quite slow on mobile devices, geometry shaders are even slower, unfortunately

Comment: @AlexBakanov Thanks for the response. 

Seems like compute shader would be my savior.